# vb.net output a result into a label on a web form

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I have linked to a Weather Web Service so pretty basic stuff and I am trying to show result in a lbl but it will not work. It works fine when I show the result in a message box. The commented line works but the label does not

```
   Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim var As String = txtCityString.Text
    lblResult.Text(weatherClient.GetWeather(var))

    'MessageBox.Show(weatherClient.GetWeather(var))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Text` is a property of the label, not a method. So you need to call

```
lblResult.Text = weatherClient.GetWeather(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
lblResult.Text = weatherClient.GetWeather(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
lblResult.Text = weatherClient.GetWeather(var)
```

Your version is not compilable. You should receive an error message stating that there is no method Text for the label and no compatible extension has been found.

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` member of `Label` is a property not a method.  In order to set it you need to do assignment

```
lblResult.Text = weatherClient.GetWeather(var)
```

The reason this is compiling today is the compiler is interpreting the `Text(...)` block as an Indexr on the return of the `Text` property.  The return type is `String` hence you are indexing into the current label text.